# Migration OpenDJ to Directory Services 6.5

Tags: directory, ldap, opendj

I'm currently use OpenDJ 2.6.4 in Suse Linux 11 and my goal is to upgraded to Directory Services 6.5.
From what I read, especialy on [Chapter 9. Before You Upgrade](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/ds/6.5/install-guide/#chap-before-you-upgrade)
and [Chapter 10. Upgrading a Directory Server](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/ds/6.5/install-guide/#chap-upgrade-ds), the process seems pretty simple, i.e, after checking Java version, backup and disable stuff we just need to execute the *upgrade* command.

This process run well or it's harder as it look?

From what I read on several [release notes](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/ds/6.5/release-notes/#features), i don't expect to have big changes on my current web application, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, there should be no change to the applications (since the interface is standard LDAPv3).

If your OpenDS service is replicated, you can upgrade one server after another, with zero downtime for the overall service.

When upgrading from 2.6, you will probably need to upgrade the Java runtime as well, since DS 6.5 requires Java 8 (and also supports 11).

So, stop a server, backup the whole server, unzip DS 6.5, upgrade Java to 8+, run upgrade, start-ds.

You might want to test the upgrade process on a dev environment. If you don’t have a dev env yet, you can create one by just copying the whole OpenDJ 2.6.4 directory and databases to a different location or another server.